# how to create a global 2d array in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

global.h:

```
extern char ** map_stage;
```

global.c: **here occours the error C2099 - Initialization is not a constant**

```
char ** map_stage=create2DCharArray(map_height,map_length*map_length);
```

function create2DCharArray:

```
char ** create2DCharArray(int m, int n)
{ 
int i;
char** array;  
array = (char**) malloc(n*sizeof(char*));  
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
   array[i] = (char*) malloc(m*sizeof(char));  
return array;
}
```

how can i get it to work?
its saying "error C2099"...
i need a global dynamic 2d array!

thank you guys!

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()` in a C program.

Comment: What's Error C2099?  Why do you have `free(array)` after your return statement?  It can't ever be reached (not that you would want it to be).

Comment: rembember that `free(array);` is unreachable. And you shouldn't free it before returning anyway.

Comment: And where does it occur?

Comment: 1) you are free'ing the array 2) you are free'ing the array AFTER you return it, which thankfully, makes it dead code

Answer (score 3):

`map_stage` is a global variable, so its initializer should be constant. You can create an initialization function to do this.

```
/* global.c */

void init(void)
{
  map_stage = create2DCharArray(map_height, map_length * map_length);
}
```

Also, notice that your `free` is unreachable.

Answer (score 2):

Error C2099 means "initializer is not a constant", which leads me to believe you've written that `map_stage` declaration at the global scope (ie, outside of any function).  That's not valid C++.

You can put the definition of the variable there, but you need to initialize it via a function call, since your initializer isn't a compile time constant.